# Why does this Mandelbrot Calculation return a circle?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, bitmap, mandelbrot

I try to calculate and display a Mandelbrot set with the following code but it always returns a circle. I think I understood the calculation but I can't find the error. Any help is very welcome. I know there are one or two other similiar questions but I think they don't address my error.

The entry point of my program is `calcMandel()`.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Mandelbrot
{
    public class MandelbrotCreator
    {
        private double accuracy;
        private int width;
        private int height;

        public MandelbrotCreator(double accuracy)
        {
            this.accuracy = accuracy;

            this.width = Convert.ToInt32(3 / this.accuracy);
            this.height = Convert.ToInt32(2 / this.accuracy);
        }

        public void calcMandel()
        {            
            double x = -2;
            double y = 1;

            int[,] values = new int[height,width];

            // Go through all values on the plane
            for (int i = 0; i < this.height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.width; j++)
                {
                    double zn = CalcZn(5, x, y);

                    values[i, j] = zn < 2 ? 0 : -16843010;  //Int Color Code for Black

                    x += this.accuracy;
                }

                x = -2;
                y -= this.accuracy;
            }

            SaveBitmap(values);
        }

        private double CalcZn (int iterations, double a, double b)
        {
            if (iterations == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            // Zn = Z(n-1)^2 + c
            return Math.Pow(CalcZn(iterations - 1, a, b), 2) + CalcC(a, b);
        }

        private double CalcC (double a, double b)
        {
            // c = Sqrt (a^2 + b^2)
            return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(a, 2) + Math.Pow(b, 2));
        }

        private void SaveBitmap(int[,] integers)
        {
            int stride = this.width * 4;

            // Copy into bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap;

            unsafe
            {
                fixed (int* intPtr = &integers[0,0])
                {
                    bitmap = new Bitmap(this.width, this.height, stride, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, new IntPtr(intPtr));
                    bitmap.Save(@".\image.bmp");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The circle]

Comment: No, you did not understand the calculation. What you are _doing_ is not the Mandelbrot equation. And doing it recursively will very soon get you into trouble.

Comment: You need to keep iterating until the complex modukus is <= 2 _or_ a maximum number of iterations is reached. The number of iterations needed then determines your color.

Comment: I'd suggest you use (or for better learning write) an abstraction class for complex numbers. So you can separate the actual calculus from the algorithm.

Comment: @Fildor Thank you, this helped me very much and after some more research I was able to get it right. I updated the question with the now working code.

Comment: I've rolled back [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58166329/revisions) which put the answer to your question into the question itself and moved the answer into [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58181204/1364007) that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote my code and this is now working perfectly for anyone who is interested. I also added a color coding for extra beauty.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Mandelbrot
{
    public class MandelbrotCreator
    {
        private double accuracy;
        private int width;
        private int height;
        private int[] colorCodes;

        public MandelbrotCreator(double accuracy)
        {
            this.accuracy = accuracy;

            this.width = Convert.ToInt32(3 / this.accuracy);
            this.height = Convert.ToInt32(2 / this.accuracy);

            // https://www.shodor.org/stella2java/rgbint.html
            this.colorCodes = new int[] { 16711680, 16716032, 16720384, 16724736, 16729088, 16733440, 16737792, 16742144, 16746496, 16750848, 16755200, 16759552, 16763904, 16768256, 16772608, 16776960, 16777060, 16777160, 16777215, 0 };
        }

        public void calcMandel()
        {            
            double x = -2;
            double y = 1;

            int[,] values = new int[height,width];

            // Go through all values on the plane
            for (int i = 0; i < this.height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.width; j++)
                {
                    int neededIterations = checkForBound(19, x, y);

                    values[i,j] = colorCodes[neededIterations - 1];

                    x += this.accuracy;
                }

                x = -2;
                y -= this.accuracy;
            }

            SaveBitmap(values);
        }

        // http://warp.povusers.org/Mandelbrot/
        private int checkForBound (int maxIterations, double c_re, double c_im)
        {
            double z_re = c_re;
            double z_im = c_im;

            int n;

            for (n = 1; n <= maxIterations; ++n)
            {
                double z_re2 = z_re * z_re;
                double z_im2 = z_im * z_im;

                if (z_re2 + z_im2 > 4)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // z(n) = z^2 + c
                z_im = 2 * z_re * z_im + c_im;
                z_re = z_re2 - z_im2 + c_re;
            }

            return n;
        }

        private void SaveBitmap(int[,] integers)
        {
            int stride = this.width * 4;

            // Copy into bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap;

            unsafe
            {
                fixed (int* intPtr = &integers[0,0])
                {
                    bitmap = new Bitmap(this.width, this.height, stride, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, new IntPtr(intPtr));
                    bitmap.Save(@".\image.bmp");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The question *was* updated with additional information - the answer. I've moved the answer from the [third revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58166329/revisions)  of the question to this answer.